# How to solve $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 \equiv \;? \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, summation

I solved expressions below . it is ok?

My attempt:

$$1)\;\;\;\;\; ?\cong\pmod n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 \stackrel{?}=   {(n-1)^3\over3}+{(n-1)^2\over2}+{(n-1)\over6}={n^3\over3}-{n^2\over6}+{n\over6}=n\left({n^2\over3}-{n\over2}+{1\over6}\right)
 $$

(continue?)how to solve for all n?

$$2)\;\;\;\;\;?\cong\pmod n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^3 = \left( {(n-1)n\over2} \right)^2$$

(continue?)how to solve for all n?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that 
First, since $n^2 =0 \pmod n$ and $n^3 =0 \pmod n$, you can calculate the sum up to $n$.

(i)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \pmod n$$

Thus, you have to decide which of the terms is divisible by 2,3. CRT tells you this is a problem modulo 6.

Now a case by case analysis solves it:

**Case 1:** $n=6k$. Then

$$ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \equiv k (n+1)(2n+1) \equiv k \equiv \frac{n}{6}  \pmod n$$

**Case 2:** $n=6k+1$. Then $n+1=2(3k+1)$ and $n+2=3(2k+1)$

$$ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \equiv n(3k+1)(2k+1) \equiv 0 \pmod n$$

the other cases are similar.

(ii) This is easier

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^3 =\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^3 =\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \pmod n$$

We only have two cases now, odd or even.

**Case 1:** $n=2k$. Then

$$ \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \equiv k^2 (n+1)^2 \equiv k^2 \equiv \frac{n^2}{4}  \pmod n$$

**Case 2:** $n=2k+1$. Then $n+1=2(k+1)$

$$ \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{2} \equiv n^2(k+1)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$$

Comment: I don't know how to identify problem is modulo 6 ,and in 2) n=2k , n= 2k+1

Comment: For the first problem you know what the top is modulo $n$, but you need to divide by $6$. You know that each of 2,3 divide one of the terms at the top, but you don't know which one... Thus the question becomes: which of $n,n+1, 2n+1$ is divisible by $2$ respectively $3$.... These are two questions modulo 2 and modulo 3... So you need to study $n$ modulo 2 and $n$ modulo 3.

Comment: @misi10 For the second question the RHS is $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$. Again, you know $n, n+1$ modulo n, but you also need to divide by $2$, and you don't know which one is divisible by $2$... That's why the two cases.

Answer (score 10):

It never hurts to gather some numerical data. For your first problem:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
n&\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\right)\bmod n&n&\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\right)\bmod n&n&\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\right)\bmod n\\ \hline
2&1&8&4&14&7\\
3&2&9&6&15&10\\
4&2&10&5&16&8\\
5&0&11&0&17&0\\
6&1&12&2&18&3\\
7&0&13&0&19&0
\end{array}$$

Examination of that table should suggest that

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\right)\bmod n=\begin{cases}
\frac{n}2,&\text{if }n\equiv 2\!\!\!\pmod 6\\\\
\frac{2n}3,&\text{if }n\equiv 3\!\!\!\pmod 6\\\\
\frac{n}2,&\text{if }n\equiv 4\!\!\!\pmod 6\\\\
0,&\text{if }n\equiv 5\!\!\!\pmod 6\\\\
\frac{n}6,&\text{if }n\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod 6\\\\
0,&\text{if }n\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod 6\;;
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

since you know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2=n\left(\frac{n^2}3-\frac{n}2+\frac16\right)=\frac16n(n-1)(2n-1)\;,$$ it shouldn’t be too hard to prove $(1)$.

**Added:** For the second problem, did you try calculating

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^3\right)\bmod n=\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}4\bmod n$$

for $n=2,3,4,\dots$ as I did for the first problem? Doing so should let you guess right away that the value is $0$ for odd $n$, and discovering the mathematical reason for this isn’t hard. If $n$ is odd, then $\frac{(n-1)^2}4$ is an integer, and clearly $n^2\frac{(n-1)^2}4\bmod n=0$.

If $n$ is even, then

$$\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}4\equiv\left(\frac{n}2\right)^2(n-1)^2\equiv\left(\frac{n}2\right)(-1)^2\equiv\left(\frac{n}2\right)^2\pmod n\;.$$

Now make a table for $n=2,4,6,\dots$:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
n:&2&4&6&8&10&12&14&16\\ \hline
\left(\frac{n}2\right)^2\bmod n:&1&0&3&0&5&0&7&0
\end{array}$$

The pattern is pretty obvious: it definitely appears that

$$\left(\frac{n}2\right)^2\bmod n=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod 4\\\\
n/2,&\text{if }n\equiv 2\!\!\!\pmod 4\;,
\end{cases}$$

and you shouldn’t have too much trouble proving that this is actually the case.

Comment: for 2) can you give me HINT?

Comment: @misi10: A hint would be *approach it the same way that I approached the first problem*, but I’ve actually done more than that.

Answer (score 2):

That problem, generalized to any exponent *m* instead of *2* is considered in the context of the [Agoh-Giuga-conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh-Giuga_conjecture), the perhaps most interesting articles about this are of [Bernd Kellner](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409259), of the [Borweins](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~dborwein/cv/giuga.pdf), and of [WD Banks](http://www.math.missouri.edu/~bbanks/papers/2009_Carmichael_Giuga.pdf) (all of them online available).       You might also consider to look at this [earlier question at MSE of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234745))

For the problem: 
$$ S_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^m \pmod n  $$
one can even heuristically arrive at the following formula:
$$ S_m(n) = n \cdot \sum_{\begin{array} {c} p | n \\ p-1 |m \end{array}} (1- \frac1p)  \pmod n $$
or, in this case
$$ S_2(n) = n \cdot \sum_{\begin{array} {c} p | n \\ p-1 |2 \end{array}} (1- \frac1p)  \pmod n $$
which, because $p=2$ and $p=3$ are the only prime where $p-1$ divides $2$
$$ S_2(n) = n\cdot ([n:3] \frac 23 + [n:2] \frac 12)   \pmod n $$
where I write $[a:b]$ for the Iverson-bracket, which evaluates to 1 if b divides a, and to zero, if not.

---

Here is some Pari/GP-code to work with this:

```
su(n)=n*(1/6 + 1/2*n + 1/3*n^2)  \\ by the known sum-formula 
                                 \\       from Bernoulli-polynomials
sumod(n) = su(n-1) % n           \\ taken modulo n

    \\ now the same by the primefactor-based formula 
sumod1(n) = ( (n % 3==0)*2*n/3 + (n % 2==0)*n/2 ) % n


\\ check this with some n
[n =8*74*3^2, sumod (n) ,  sumod1 (n)]
```

Comment: How to arrive $ S_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^m \pmod n  $ --> $ S_m(n) = \sum_{\begin{array} {c} p | n \\ p-1 |m \end{array}} (1- \frac1p)  \pmod n $ and write out more?

Comment: @misi10: I found it myself by examination of the pattern of the results which I got using the original formulation of the problem with various m. But Kellner, and I think Banks (but with the latter I am not sure), gives a proof for that identity as far as I recall...