# $1^k+2^k+\cdots+(p-1)^k\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

How can I show this equation

$$1^k+2^k+\cdots+(p-1)^k\equiv 0 \pmod{p},$$

where $k$ is integer that $p-1\nmid k$ and $p$ is odd prime.

Comment: I am assuming you meant $k$ does not divide $p-1?$

Comment: I think the correct conditions are $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is odd.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234745/is-my-shorter-expression-for-s-mn-1m2m3m-cdotsn-1m-pmod-n-true/234759#234759  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385936/p-prime-1-le-k-le-p-2-there-exists-x-in-mathbbz-xk-neq-0-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of presentation is too choose such $a$ that $a^k\ne 1(\mod p)$ and
note that $0,a,2a,... (p-1)a$ form complete residue system modulo $p.$ Multiplying the sum by $a^k$ we arrive at 
$S=a^kS(\mod p)$ and thus $S=0 (\mod p).$

P.S. Such $a$ exists for any prime $p,$ one may take primitive root $\mod p.$

Comment: In fact this solution works for any $k$ that isn't a multiple of $p-1$ (even if $p=2$ for that matter), which is precisely the condition in the original question. Just take $a$ to be a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: Thanks Greg, the question was modified after I submitted the answer. I've edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From Fermat's little theorem $x^{p-1}-1=0$ (mod p). Mod p, the polynomial has p-1 solutions, basically the integers from one to $p-1$. Since most of the terms in this polynomial are zero, all the symmetric polynomials in these numbers of order less than $p-1$ are zero. Therefore any symmetric polynomial in these numbers of order less than $p-1$ will be $0$ (mod p).