# Prove that the statement $(1+2+3+ \cdots + n) \mid (1^m+2^m+3^m+ \cdots +n^m)$ is true for all odd numbers $m$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction, education

My first idea to this problem is proved by induction (obviously by induction). So I tried to solve it by Induction, but after 30-45 minutes it just didn't give me enough information to prove it. Also I tried both weak and strong induction and get nothing.

Comment: You are lacking a good explanation and a show of what you tried.... This question might be closed

Comment: Can you tell me what does that "|" mean in your question please

Comment: @Gwen is divisible with no remainder

Comment: @Masd thank you so much

Comment: As I am understanding you are trying to prove that:
$$\forall m =2u+1,\,u\in\mathbb{N}\, \,\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\ni\left.\sum_{k=1}^n\right|\sum_{y=1}^n y^m$$

The first sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

The second one becomes as found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula,

$$\sum_{y=1}^ny^m = \frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{m+1}{r}B_rn^{p-r+1}$$

Comment: @Masd Just one more question. After "|" there is 1^m which can divide any number without remainder. I am really sorry that I am unable to understand this. Can you explain more elaborately? I can't even find such notation on google

Comment: @Gwen he actually didn't use the brackets....the real expression is $$(1+2+3+ \cdots + n)\mid (1^m+2^m+3^m+ \cdots +n^m)$$ and now it is same as if $a|b$ then $b\equiv 0 mod a$

Comment: Consider $k^m$ and $(n-k)^m$ mod $n$ for odd $m$. Also, consider $k^m$ and $(n+1-k)^m$ mod $n+1$ for odd $m$.

Comment: @robjohn can you please write a full prove about it? Thank you!

Comment: The question needs some [added context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). When context is added, answers can be given.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I have solved it with modular arithmetic...

Comment: If you post your answer, it will help others with the same question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234745/is-my-shorter-expression-for-s-mn-1m2m3m-cdotsn-1m-pmod-n-true and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385936/p-prime-1-le-k-le-p-2-there-exists-x-in-mathbbz-xk-neq-0-1

Answer (score 1):

Do you know modular arithmetic?  This problem is much clearer to understand in that setting (it becomes obvious why the exponent $m$ is being taken as odd), while it seems totally opaque and strange as a plain induction problem.

Update: since you know modular arithmetic, then in order to show
$1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m \equiv 0 \bmod n(n+1)/2$, take cases if $n$ is even or odd.

Suppose $n$ is even, so $n(n+1)/2 = (n/2)(n+1)$ where $n/2$ and $n+1$ are relatively prime.  Mod $n$, we have
$$
1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m \equiv 1^m + 2^m + \cdots + (n-1)^m \bmod n
$$
and $j^m + (n-j)^m \equiv j^m + (-j)^m \equiv j^m - j^m \equiv 0 \bmod n$ because $m$ is odd.  Thus the sums $1^m + (n-1)^m$, $2^m + (n-2)^m$, and so on all vanish mod $n$.  The only term that survives is the solitary term $(n/2)^m$, so
$$
1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m \equiv (n/2)^m \bmod n.
$$
Now reduce modulo $n/2$ to kill off the right side, giving us
$1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m \equiv 0 \bmod n/2$ when $n$ is even.

Next, show $1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m \equiv 0 \bmod n+1$ because $j^m + (n+1-j)^m \equiv 0 \bmod n+1$, and these pairings account for everything on the left side since there is no middle term this time: $n+1$ is odd when $n$ is even.

Thus when $n$ is even, $1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m$ is divisible by $n/2$ and by $n+1$, which are relatively prime, so that sum is divisble by $n(n+1)/2$.

The case of odd $n$ is similar and left to you.

Comment: It will be more suitable as a comment I guess.

Comment: Yes I know modular arithmetic, but how you used it on this problem, I think you have to use induction :)

Comment: You don't need induction, except in a very pedantic way perhaps.  I have updated my answer to show how everything falls into place when you allow yourself to use modular arithmetic (in the case $n$ is even; you can do odd $n$ in a similar way).  I do not regard this as an induction problem. It's really a nice example of using modular arithmetic.